# Unable to perform scrubber slider movement using ruby selenium

Tags: ruby, selenium

I need to slide through the scrubber bar:

```
<div id="scrubber" class="no-highlight expanded" style="outline: none;">
 <div id="progress" style="width: 50%; outline: none;">
  <div id="handle" class="grabbed" style="outline: none;">
   <div class="overhandle no-highlight" style="outline: none;">
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

But my code seems to have no effect on the bar

```
hnd = br.find_element(:id,'handle')
br.action.drag_and_drop_by(hnd,100,0).click.perform
```

the same code seems to work in http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/

I also tried to change the style of the element(id : progress) using javascript but only shows the updated width when i query the same in irb.

javascript_execution:

```
br.execute_script('document.getElementById("progress").style.width = "20%"')
```

I am using chrome as my browser.

Answer (score 0):

Executing a jQuery script should work just fine.

```
jQuery( "#slider" ).slider( "option", "value", 60 );
```

Tested on the same slider in the iframe page http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/slider/default.html